# attribute 'colors' doesn't work in the tree tag that located inside the form view

Tags: styles, odoo, openerp-7

Without speaking a lot this is the piece of code I'm working on :

```
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Sales Order" version="7.0">
            <!-- some codes -->
            <field name="order_line">
                <tree string="Sales Order Lines" editable="bottom" colors = "red:price_unit &lt; 10.0">
                    <!-- some fields -->
                    <field name="price_unit"/>
                    <field name="discount"/>
                    <field name="price_subtotal"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

What i want is : coloring sales order line with red colors if the unit_price < 10.0 as you see in the code i express it like that : `<tree ... colors="red:unit_price &lt; 10.0">`, But when I test it to see the result, It doesn't work.

Do you have guys any idea why it doesn't work, or someone has a suggestion to reach that result with a different way; maybe by using JS.

Comment: Which specific Odoo version do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 7

Comment: Try to set the relevant tag next time. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you,I will

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using color attribute, use `decoration-{danger/info/..}` attribute. Also, use `&lt;` or `&gt;` inside xml for `<` or `>`.

```
<tree string="Sales Order Lines" editable="bottom" decoration-danger="price_unit &lt; 10">
```

***This answer is applicable for newer versions of Odoo (10 or later)***

Comment: This question is about Openerp/Odoo 7. Try to edit a hint, that your answer is about newer verions, where `decoration-*` was introduced. I think it was introduced with Odoo 9 or 10.

Comment: ohh totally missed that `openerp-7` tag. thanks for reminding!!

Comment: it was added by me after you've written your answer, that's why i've written my first comment at all ;-)